# how to retrive just 10 items per page in django

Tags: django, django-models, query-optimization, django-queryset

Iam trying to use pagination in my web page. So I found a example in the django documentation
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage

def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    # Make sure page request is an int. If not, deliver first page.
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1

    # If page request (9999) is out of range, deliver last page of results.
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('list.html', {"contacts": contacts})
```

Problem here in the example is he is loading all the items at once to paginate. But in my database there are `20000` entries and all of them cant be loaded at once . So, is there a way to optimise the query?

Comment: are you sure it's loading all the items at once?  QuerySets() are lazy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Comment: I think so it used to load faster when there were `1000` entries in my database. Now when the items size increased to `20000` its loading very slow.

Comment: Have you tried the interactive shell? Try to execute your code, little by little (remember not to type "contact_list" since that will load all the items in the queryset). You might see exactly which part is taking so long. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If it does load all objects into memory at once, then it is a bug. As long as you don't cast your `QuerySet`s explicitly to lists before feeding them to `Paginator`, the paginator only fetches the number of rows matching the `QuerySet` using one query and then limits the `QuerySet` appropriately to only fetch those rows that are to be displayed.

If you really suspect it is loading all the objects, to verify this, use the [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and look at the executed queries. If it does indeed load everything, then please file a bug in Django's trac.

Answer (score 1):

Set `DEBUG` to `False` in settings.py, which will dramatically improve your performance. Debug mode (among other things) turns on SQL caching which can slow down things considerably.